# Mail send to my domain ends up in local inbox instead of exchange server

Tags: email, postfix

I'm running a MediaWiki install under Ubuntu Server 10.10. I have configured it to use the standard php `mail()` function with my local mail delivery agent (postfix). The mail gets sent from the MediaWiki site, but the only problem is that whenever the address it's meant to be sent to is on the same domain as the server, those mails get delivered to local inboxes on the Ubuntu server.

So basically, the server is `linuxbox.companydomain.com`, and our e-mails are `name@companydomain.com`. Any mail sent to an address like that simply ends up in the user's local inbox, e.g. a message to `anders@companydomain.com` ends up in `/home/anders/mbox`, while a message to `anders@gmail.com` would end up in the correct gmail inbox.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mails to `name@companydomain.com` end up in a local inbox because Postfix is configured to use [local(8)](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) delivery for the `companydomain.com` domain. Most likely this happens because `companydomain.com` is listed in the [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) parameter, either explicitly or implicitly (because for example [myhostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname) is `companydomain.com` and [mydestination](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) is at its default value which includes `$myhostname`).

So try setting `mydestination=`. If that doesn't help, edit your question and post output of the following commands to give more information on your setup:

- `postconf -n`
- `postconf mydestination`
- `postconf myhostname`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is probably what is called a "smarthost" setup. Basically, you set up Postfix to pass everything on to a different SMTP server.

This is controlled by the [`relayhost`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) configuration parameter in Postfix's `main.cf`.

You may also need to adjust other settings, particularly [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination), for this to work.